# notifyDataSetChanged poor performance with viewpager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with four fragments. Users fills in data on the first fragment, hits a button, data goes to sqlite. The other three fragments is then used to display the data in the sqlite DB in various ways. The first one being just listing them in a listview. Problem is the data does not get updated on the fragments, until I get to the last fragment screen en swap back. So I was thinking it's maybe something to do with setOffscreenPageLimit which I set to

```
mypager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

in the onCreate of my ViewPager, does not seem to have any affect.
Then I thought override onPageSelected and in there add

```
mypager.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This works, however the swipes between the fragments is sluggish. If I take it out again and swipe this the last fragment and then the fragments update, it's very quick.
Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the ViewPager, however, every time you call notifyDataSetChanged() the pager will fetch the data from the DB.

Instead of updating the cursor every time the page changes, I would recommend creating a function to check if the dataset has actually changed before making a call to notifyDataSetChanged(). This way you will only have a performance penalty when a user changes data on Page1, but from there onward all page swipes would be instant, until the data is changed again.

Hope this helps your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to slide fragments smoothly, run long-to-execute code in onCreateView() with some delay, for example, 150-250ms.

Transition animation is executed is UI thread, so if you run anything else taking significant time (SQLite db access, for example), in the same time, smoothness of transition suffers.

```
YourFragments extends Fragment {

...
Handler mHanlder = new Handler();

  @Override
  public void onCreate(...){

  ...
  mHandler.postDelayed(someRunnable, 250);
  ...
  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure this is the correct way to do it, need to investigate it a little more. It's interesting how if you swipe to a fragment off screen and back to the fragment with the listview it's updated very, very quickly, and that's what I want, just off the first swipe :)